# Are the side pockets of the Proviz Switch Men's Cycling Jacket - Yellow / Reflective accessible from both sides?

Tags: clothes, jacket

I'm considering buying the
http://provizsports.com/en-gb/switch-mens-cycling-jacket-yellow-reflective.html
jacket. Its description states "Two side pockets". As the jacket is reversible, are the pockets accessible when worn either way? Or are there 4 pockets with 2 facing each way? The pictures don't make it clear.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the shop?

Comment: Not an answer, but the photos show zippers in both configurations (and I think it’s not the ventilation). I just wonder *where* the pockets are. Are they simply sandwiched between the inside and outside layer and can be accessed in both configurations? Probably small volume. But front pockets are bad for cycling anyway.

Comment: it's hard to say, I would suggest contacting either the shop or manufacturer as ojs previously suggested